# "Stability concern" or "instability concern"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

If I am unsure whether something is stable, would I have **stability concerns** or **instability concerns**?

Comment: Google Books claims more writers are [concerned about stability](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22concerned+about+stability%22) than are [concerned about **instability**,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22concerned+about+instability%22) but I'd say it's an effectively "meaningless" stylistic choice.

Comment: It depends on your larger context. Context-less questions are impossible to answer. Also, this could refer to a built structure or a person or whatever,.....

Answer (score 2):

I think it is more natural in English to "be concerned about (the) stability" than to "have stability concerns."

But between the two, "stability concerns" is correct because you have concerns about the stability (of the structure, etc.).

So you could say something like, "I have stability concerns regarding the new design. Removing the supports may cause instability." But in my opinion it would be more natural to say it like, "I am concerned about the stability of the new design. Removing the supports may cause instability."

Comment: It depends. It could be either or both or  neither.

Comment: It also sounds natural to "be concerned about potential (or imminent) instability" and thus to have "instability concerns." Neither choice is incorrect in the context of general technical writing.